# Align QML TabView content with another item, so that tabBar overlaps with that item

Tags: qml, tabview

I would like the actual Tab contents inside a TabView to anchor or line up to the bottom of another visual element. In this case the tabBar at the top would overlap with the other element in question.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the y coordinate of the Tab contents of the TabView or alternatively, how to get the height of the tab buttons in the tabBar so I can offset the alignment based on it.

I can think of 2 ways to solve this, both of which are clunky:
Option 1 -- I could make a TabView with no contents, which sits inside my other element. Then I could make a second TabView with tabsVisible = false. Then link the 2 together.

Option 2 -- I could override tab: in TabViewStyle, set a height for it from a property, that way I could offset my TabView.y based on the tabBar height.

Option 3: Somehow get the y coordinate of a Tab content within TabView (relative to the TabView or the parent item) or somehow get the existing tab (button) height. I have no idea how to do either of these.

Options 1 and 2 seem very clunky. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can get this information very easily. `TabView` define a [`contentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tabview.html#contentItem-prop) property, which holds the content item of the tab view. The tab button height is therefore `tabView.height - tabView.contentItem.height`

Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

Item {
    width: 350
    height: 150

    TabView
    {
        id: tabview
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width/2
        Component.onCompleted: {addTab("1");addTab("2")}
    }

    Column
    {
        anchors.left: tabview.right
        anchors.right: parent.right
        Rectangle
        {
            width: parent.width
            height: tabview.height-tabview.contentItem.height
            color: "red"
        }
        Rectangle
        {
            width: parent.width
            color: "yellow"
            height: tabview.contentItem.height
        }
    }
}
```